# Track User with DLookup

Tags: vba

This code will update a table (tbl_DateTracking) with the active users id (NBK) and it updates the records based on two values `CaseID` and `OCC_Scenario`.

**Here is the problem:** we only want to add the id to the current record being recorded.  The problem is that all the records that have the CaseID/OCC_Scenario are getting updated with the user id.  In other words, the old records are being changed.

Can anyone see what to add to this code to say: this current record only, add the id???

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[NBK]", "Employees", "[Status]=1")) Then
Retval = MsgBox("Login information not found - Please choose your role manually", vbOKOnly, "Login Error")
     Else
log = DLookup("[NBK]", "Employees", "[Status]=1")

SQLnbk = " Update tbl_DateTracking SET NBK = "
SQLnbk = SQLnbk & "'" & log & "' WHERE "
SQLnbk = SQLnbk & "CaseId = '" & CaseId & "' AND OCC_Scenario = '" & OCC_Scenario & "';"
End If
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLnbk
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are updating records in a form. You can refer to controls on the form, for example:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("[NBK]", "Employees", "[Status]=1")) Then
   Retval = MsgBox( _
      "Login information not found - Please choose your role manually", _
      vbOKOnly, "Login Error")
Else
   log = DLookup("[NBK]", "Employees", "[Status]=1")
   Me.txtNBK=log
```

End If

If you are using a query, you will need a unique ID. For example:

```
SQLnbk = " Update tbl_DateTracking SET NBK = "
SQLnbk = SQLnbk & "'" & log & "' WHERE "
SQLnbk = SQLnbk & "UniqueID = " & Me.UniqueID

<...>
CurrentDB.Execute SQLnbk, dbFailOnError
```